# CGI table error

Tags: perl, html-table, cgi, internal-server-error

I'm trying to display a table with some information and I have this code for that:

```
print $q->start_html(-title => "user summary");

print $q->table({-border=>1},
                   $q->tr($q->th(["Info","Value"])),#header
                   $q->tr($q->td(["Date",$date_var])),#first row
                   $q->tr($q->td(["Uptime",$uptime])),#second row
                   $q->tr($q->td(["1 min",$avg_one])),#third row
                   $q->tr($q->td(["5 min",$avg_two])),#fourth row
                   $q->tr($q->td(["15 min",$avg_two])),#fifth row
                   );
```

but when I run it I get:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>user summary</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
Undefined subroutine CGI::tr
 at ./index.cgi line 30
```

where `./index.cgi line 30` refer to this line `print $q->table({-border=>1` and on the webpage I get `500 Internal Server Error`

so any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is

```
$q->Tr(...)
```

rather than

```
$q->tr(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr` is a synonym of `y`, the translation operator. Use `Tr` for CGI's table row.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right answer (twice) already, but I just wanted to point you at the "[Non-Standard HTML Shortcuts](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#NON-STANDARD-HTML-SHORTCUTS)" section of the [CGI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI), which says:

> A few HTML tags don't follow the standard pattern for various reasons.
>
> **comment()** generates an HTML comment (). Call it like
>
> `print comment('here is my comment');`
>
> Because of conflicts with built-in Perl functions, the following
>   functions begin with initial caps:
>
> - Select
> - Tr
> - Link
> - Delete
> - Accept
> - Sub
>
> In addition, start_html(), end_html(), start_form(), end_form(),
>   start_multipart_form() and all the fill-out form tags are special. See
>   their respective sections.

Comment: My point is that the answer is usually in the documentation and that more people should read it :-)